# How to send push notification from Firebase to web app on iOS device?

Tags: php, ios, laravel, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

everyone, I would like to ask how to send push notification from Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) to web app on iOS device? I am having the problem on receiving the push notification from FCM when I turned on the web app on iOS device. However, there is no issue to receive the push notification from FCM when the web app had been turned on on the android device.

The following programming languages that I am using:

1. front-end for web app - HTML, CSS, JavaScript
2. back-end for web server - PHP Laravel, MySQL
3. way to push notification - Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM)

Should I subscribe the membership for Apple developer in order to get the push notification from FCM on iOS device?

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Push notifications don't work for IOS with web apps only native apps can do this. You could use a firebase cloud function to message the user phone number though.

Comment: Hi, @Joeman, may I know what if I get the authentication key as Apple Developer? Is that possible to receive push notification for iOS with web apps? as according to this https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/certs, it claims that needs authentication key to get push notification for iOS with web apps, but I am not sure if it is managed to get it on web apps.

Comment: @EdisonToh unfortunately there is no way to get push notifications through a web app on IOS. While this could change in the future as of right now the only things that can access push notifications on ios are native apps. Check this out for a little more info https://www.izooto.com/blog/ios-safari-push-notifications-in-2021 A work around would be to just send message notifications. Or do some platform checking and send texts if the user is on ios and push notifications if the user is on android.

Comment: Thanks for your information, okay, I will look into native app development, thanks.